# Attendance Report Missing Select Participants

Tags: microsoft-teams

Has anyone seen an issue where an Attendance Report doesn't have everyone in attendance?

I have a user who, last Friday, didn't have an Attendance Report option at all. After a reboot, the option now shows, but when they downloaded the csv, it was missing 3 people who were definitely in the meeting.

My googling can't find any direction on this, so if anyone's seen this before, that'd be great.

Comment: Hi @CluelessSysAdmin Are you facing this issue every time or only once?

Answer (score 0):

For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.